# Does jest --watch or --watchAll ignore --runInBand option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have some db integration tests that are running using the `--runInBand` option.

`yarn test integration` is what I run in CI.

`yarn test:i` adds a `-- --watchAll` and I use that for local development.

Unfortunately, any time I have any file changes, my tests break because they seem to run in parallel.  Is there something I can do to make sure watch runs the tests again with `--runInBand`?

Comment: It seems it may be related to this https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/6647